# Batching in Java and Excel gives different results

Tags: java, list, hashmap, batch-processing

I need to batch elements that have similar client id (String type, but at the moment only numeric values, like "12345", "235134", etc.)

```
Map<String, List<Client>> _batched = new HashMap<String, List<Client>>();
for (Client c : _Clients)
{
    String id = c.getIdClient();
    List<Client> clients = _batched.get(id);
    if(_clients == null){
        clients = new ArrayList<Client>();
        _batched.put(id, clients);
    }
    clients.add(c);
}
```

The problem is that when I compare this function with the results of Excel (`=SUM(IF(FREQUENCY(C2:C618,C2:C618)>0,1))`), then I get different results, i.e. 526 and 519.

Is something wrong with my code?

Comment: Not sure if you just typed the code wrong in the question, but you seem to be using `_clients` and `clients` to refer to the same list inside of the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
String id = c.getIdClient();
List<Client> _clients = _batched.get(id);
if(_clients == null){
    pois = new ArrayList<Client>();
    _batched.put(id, _clients);
}
_clients.add(c);
```

You create a new array into a variable called `pois` but then put the contents of the variable `_clients` into `_batched`. What happens with the value put into `pois`?

I don't understand how that doesn't null pointer exception actually.

Comment: Thanks. Please see the edited post. Sorry, it was my typewriting error. But the issue is still the same.

Comment: Where do you get the final count from? (How do you generate that in Java)